# How do I get the URI of a file saved with FileOutputStream?

Tags: java, android, uri, android-file

Here's the code that saves an image file to... somewhere? How do I get the URI for the file "webimage"?

```
Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        String fileName = "webImage";//no .png or .jpg needed
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            FileOutputStream fo = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            // remember close file output
            fo.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: The file will be saved in getFilesDir(). But you better use absolute paths to know before where you put it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [getFileStreamPath()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFileStreamPath(java.lang.String)) like this:

```
String fileName = "webImage";
//...
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath(fileName));
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out I think:

```
final File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "webImage");
Uri weburi = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Uri.fromFile(imageFile)`, where `imageFile` is an instance of `File`